# Как получить год, месяц, день?

Tags: java, дата

Здравствуйте! Я работаю на java и мало опыта. Как получить год, месяц, день. Очень жду ответа

```
class date{

 int Date;
 int Month;
 int Year;
Date myDay;
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

public date(){

  myDay = calendar.getTime();

  Date=myDay.getDay();
  Month=myDay.getMonth();
  Year=myDay.getYear();

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar;

 int Date;
 int Month;
 int Year;

public static void main(String args[]) {

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

Date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
Year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  }
```